# Wix Toolset v4 Shortcut & installation directory per login user

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2012, scope, shortcut-file, wix4

Using WiX Toolset v4 & Heatwave plugin from Visual Studio, I just try to add shortcut to current user Desktop but have a hard time doing it. My install directory is Id="ProgramFilesFolder".

- my goal is have shortcut at C:\Users\{User}\Desktop\ and installation at C:\Program Files (x86)
  Anyone know how to do it?

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">
  <Package Name="Package"
           Manufacturer="Company"
           Version="1.0.0.0"
           Scope="perMachine"
           UpgradeCode="{PUT-GUID-HERE}">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ShortcutGroup" />
    </Feature>

    <!--Add User Interface dialog-->
    <ui:WixUI
            Id="WixUI_InstallDir"
            InstallDirectory="InstallProductFolder" />
    <!--InstallDirectory="DesktopFolder"/>-->
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

I did try to set Scope tag to different values

- When I set the Scope to **perUserOrMachine**

  - I got the Desktop shortcut in correct place like C:\Users{User}\Desktop\  While the installation directory would messed up and go like C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\
- When I set the Scope to **perMachine**

  - I got Desktop shortcut put into public Desktop like C:\Users\Public\Desktop while the installation is correct at C:\Program Files (x86)

Answer (score 0):

The third possible value for `Scope` is `perUser`,
 just change `Scope="perUser"` in order to get disared location of your shortcut `C:\Users\{User}\Desktop`
For more details take a look official documentation: [PackageScopeType](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/packagescopetype/)